# Datatable Reload page after click Page Number 2 or Next Page

Tags: php, datatables

In my project I want datatable to display record on website in PHP.

My question is that if we click on Page Number 2 or next Page than page must reload and than come back to the page 2 or next page.

Is there anyone who can help me with this.

Comment: if u want without reload use ajax in that.

Comment: @MohitKumar My question is, In datatable if i click Next Page or Page No.2 than page must be reload, currently its not.

Answer (score 0):

As Mohit said, if you want serverside processing with a PHP script, you'll need to define the Ajax properties. There's some good examples on the DataTables website for this - look [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/index.html) and [here](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/index.html).

Comment: I want to reload the page when i click on Next Page or Page No.2 in Datatable.